# Laravel 9 Database\Factories\AffiliateFactory::forCompany(): Argument #1 ($company) must be of type Database\Factories\Company, array given

Tags: php, laravel, factory

I'm trying to associate an `Affiliate` with my `User` and `Company` in my affiliate factory within my Laravel 9 proect.

Every time I run my seeder, the following error is thrown:

> Database\Factories\AffiliateFactory::forCompany(): Argument #1 ($company) must be of type Database\Factories\Company, array given

I intentionally need to pass the user and company id's through because I need to set them in my affiliate factory's definition so that they're assigned correctly.

How do I resolve this error.

My `AffiliateFactory`:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Affiliate;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AffiliateFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Affiliate::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $affiliate = 'aff'.Str::random(4);
        $apiHash = Str::random(32);

        return [
            'aff_id' => 'aff'.Str::random(4),
            'description' => rand(0, 100) > 50 ? $this->faker->sentence() : null,
            'api_key' => md5($affiliate.$apiHash),
            'api_hash' => $apiHash,
            'allow_submission' => $this->faker->boolean(),
            'is_favourited' => $this->faker->boolean(),
            'is_default' => $this->faker->boolean(),
            'is_enabled' => true,
            'last_used_at' => Carbon::now()->subHours(rand(0, 72))->subMinutes(rand(0, 60))
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Set the company for this factory
     *
     * @param Company $company
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
     */
    public function forCompany(Company $company)
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) use ($company) {
            return [
                'user_id' => $company->user_id,
                'company_id' => $company->id,
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

Called via:

```php
// create our users
$users = User::factory(10)->create();

// assign one company to each user
foreach ($users as $user) {
    Company::factory()->for($user)->count(1)->create();
}

$companies = Company::all();

foreach ($companies as $company) {
    Affiliate::factory(50)->forCompany([
        'user_id' => $company->user_id,
        'company_id' => $company->id
    ])->create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the model `App\Models\Company` in the `AffiliateFactory`, that's the reason why it's searching for a `Company` class in the namespace of class `AffiliateFactory`.

Just include your model at the top and it should work.

```
use App\Models\Company;

// now uses App\Models\Company instead of Database\Factories\Company;
public function forCompany(Company $company) {
 ...
}
```